# Generate random values in oracle view

Tags: oracle

I have a table like shown in picture. For a distinct combination of VALUE1 and VALUE2 Columns, i have several steps. So, I want a view showing the number of each step based on the order they arrive. For example, STEP1 arrives first and so it's step number in the view should be 1 and so on. Kindly heklp me on this aspect. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: First: what's the title has to do with your question? Second, what is "the order they arrive"? Is there a field, a code, something like that?!

Comment: i mean the order in which they appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask can pe done with:

```
select value1, value2, step, row_number() over (partition by value1, value2 order by rn)
from 
    (select value1, value2, step, rownum as rn
    from table
    --an order by recommended
)
```

But I strongly recommend to give an order by to the query. The "the order they arrive" is not an order in a DBMS.

Comment: @Florin....Hello...thank you very much. This is what i expect. But, instead of partition by step order by rn, we need to use partition by value1,value2 order by rn

Answer (score 0):

To get the step number in a seperate field, use the `substr` function:

```
CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT value1, value2, step, substr(step,-1) as "Step Number"
FROM table;
```

Comment: Hi...thanks for ur reply...the values in step need not alwasy start with the name 'STEP'...So i guess we cant use substr here..Thank you

Comment: Ah, I was unsure how exactly the number is determined. In that case the answer from @FlorinGhita is more what you're looking for.